# converting int or float into bytes array in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, code-optimization, data-type

I am trying to send data from one arduino to another over ethernet using udp protocol.
In arduino writing data over udp is like this

```
UDP.write(buffer, size);
```

where buffer is an array to send as a series of bytes and size is the size of the array.

Now, i am reading a sensor value from a0 pin of the arduino it will be stored either in int or float type variable. As mentioned earlier udp only sends byte type array. so all i want to do is convert the value stored in the variable to the byte type array.
my variable will be.

```
pinMode(A0,INPUT);
int data;
byte data_array[Size];
```

and in loop

```
data=analogRead(A0);
```

now i have convert this value in data_array;

Please provide the suggestion with proper explanation.
Thank you

Comment: `UDP.write((const byte*) &data, sizeof(data));`